# $\pm 1$ matrices with constant row and column sums

Tags: matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am facing matrices in which every entry is $\pm 1$ and every row and column sums to the same constant, e.g.,

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
     1  &  -1  &  -1  &   1  &  -1\\
    -1  &  -1  &  -1   &  1    & 1\\
    -1  &   1   &  1   & -1   & -1\\
     1  &   1  &  -1   & -1   & -1\\
    -1  &  -1  &   1   & -1   &  1\end{pmatrix}.$$

They are closely related to $(0, 1)$-matrices with the same property, as $\frac{1}{2}M+J$ results in such a matrix. Are there some references/theory/research/results on such matrices?

Comment: Square matrices?

Comment: Do you want to optimize some function over the set of such matrices?

Comment: You want to enumerate them? To simulate them? Or what?

Comment: The vector with all ones is an eigenvector. Otherwise it’s just a generic (-1,1)- matrix.